# How to type Chinese vertically from the right to the left?

Tags: writing

Is there an easy way in Word or Text or other software to type Chinese vertically from the right to the left, such as the following?

[image]

Comment: It totally depends on your typesetting software and this is off-topic

Comment: It's unclear whether software-related questions are on-topic, as discussed here:
https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237/faq-what-is-on-topic-and-off-topic-on-this-site
https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/about-software-questions-site-faq

Comment: Best to make clear what os you are talking anout — windows, mac, ios, or android

Comment: @TomGewecke, I mostly use windows. But if you happen to know how it works in android, it would be great.

Comment: Sorry, only know Mac and iOS.

Comment: I'll close this as a duplicate: the other question has the same answer along with other answers and remarks.

Answer (score 4):

In MS Word select **Text Direction** and change it to *vertical*.

[image]

Word needs to have East Asian language features enabled to do this.

Word for Mac looks slightly different:

[image]

Comment: To supplement： there are vertical text tool in other softwares like Photoshop.